# Is server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0' necessary?

Tags: cherrypy, ipv4

When configuring my Cherrypy web application, I found out on stackoverflow that the following setting is needed:

```
[global]
server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0'
```

This is basically IPv4 INADDR_ANY, meaning "listen on all interfaces".
However, I don't understand why you would ever need to listen on **all** interfaces? I've looked up but didn't find any satisfactory explanations.

Comment: Because why find out which interfaces exist and which are specifically the ones the user wants to bind if there is a constant that will generally just work. It probably doesn't *need* to do that. If you want you can bind it to a specific interface. But 0.0.0.0 is often used as default because it just works without any extra steps

Comment: @edave Does `interface` in this context mean the same as your host ip address?

Comment: An interface in this context is a connection to a network. They are identified by the IP you have in that network. E.g. my personal PC is connected by wire with my home network with the IP "192.168.50.14". But because I use Virtual Machines on my PC, it is also connected with a virtual switch where it has the IP "172.31.208.1".

Giving one of those IPs means it will only listen to that specific network. But because of DHCP, these IPs tend to change. 0.0.0.0 means it will be reachable on all these connections, regardless of what IP I was given.

Comment: @edave so basically just stick with the setting `0.0.0.0` will be ok? no need to opitmize further in this regard, right?

Comment: Yes. There is another nuance: The loopback interface. If you are on a test or private installation and only want the server to be reachable on the same machine and not any network, you can set it to 127.0.0.1 or "localhost". But if want to reach it from other computers, use 0.0.0.0. You only need to change that if you really, explicitly don't want it to react to some interfaces.